# Selenium IDE, [error] Element name.... not found

Tags: selenium

Trying Selenium IDE. I'm getting an intermittent error, I've tried slowing down the IDE but it still happens. I start w/google and search for fishbase, I then click search fishbase link - then "common name is" and I put Taron in and like the top-most "usa" link. Usually it gets error at the same place "[error] Element name=CommonName not found", 9 times out of ten it has a problem there. I hope I've provided enough info. Using Ubuntu 11.10 and FF 11.0. I have a very fast connection but move the slider to slow. Why does this problem occur?

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>fishbase</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=em</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=CommonName</td>
    <td>Tarpon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=input[type=&quot;button&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Tarpon</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

It worked the 1st time but not the 2nd time...thanks.

```
[info] Executing: |open | / | |
[info] Executing: |type | id=gbqfq | fishbase |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | css=em | |
[info] Executing: |type | name=CommonName | Tarpon |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | css=input[type="button"] | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | link=Tarpon | |
[info] Executing: |open | / | |
[info] Executing: |type | id=gbqfq | fishbase |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | css=em | |
[info] Executing: |type | name=CommonName | Tarpon |
[error] Element name=CommonName not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
 <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>css=em</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>7000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>name=CommonName</td>
        <td>Tarpon</td>
    </tr>
```

Or just put pause before command `type| name=CommonName  |Tarpon`

Comment: try to avoid using of `pause` where it is possible, because it is a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

You can add `waitForElementPresent` command. Works with fastest IDE parameter:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>fishbase</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=em</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=em</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>name=CommonName</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=CommonName</td>
    <td>Tarpon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=input[type=&quot;button&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=input[type=&quot;button&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Tarpon</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```